# Rails search form with radio buttons to select search conditons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a simple rails search implemented in my app. At the time I did it, I just needed to get the job done, however I'm sure the way I did it was far from DRY, so any suggestions as to how to improve this would be greatly appreciated. I basically want a search text box, with 4 radio buttons which the use selects to choose what they want to search.

My current index:

```
<%= form_tag("/search", :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for Product Title:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search Title") %>
<% end %>
<br>
<%= form_tag("/search", :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:d, "Search for Product Description:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:d) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search Description") %>
<% end %>
<br>
<%= form_tag("/search", :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:a, "Search for Category Names:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:a) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search Category Name") %>
<% end %>
<br>
<%= form_tag("/search", :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:i, "Search for ID Str:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:i) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search ID Str") %>
<% end %>

<<results from search here>>
```

Controller:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:commit] == "Search Title"
      # Great, now lets figure out what sort of query we're after
      @searchQuery_title = params[:q]
      @resultsReceived_title = true
      if 
         @sqlResults_title_published_size = Product.where("title like ? AND published like ?", "%" + params[:q] + "%", '1')
         @sqlResults_title_size = Product.where("title like ? OR categories like ?", "%" + params[:q] + "%", "%" + params[:q] + "%")
         @sqlResults_title = Product.where("title like ? OR categories like ?", "%" + params[:q] + "%", "%" + params[:q] + "%").page(params[:page]).per(200).order("published DESC")
      end
    else
      @resultsReceived_title = false
      @sqlResults_title = []
    end

     if params[:commit] == "Search Description"
        # Great, now lets figure out what sort of query we're after
        @searchQuery_descr = params[:d]
        @resultsReceived_descr = true
        if 
           @sqlResults_descr_published_size = Product.where("long_descr like ? AND published = ?", "%" + params[:d] + "%", '1')
           @sqlResults_descr_size = Product.where("long_descr like ?", "%" + params[:d] + "%")
           @sqlResults_descr = Product.where("long_descr like ?", "%" + params[:d] + "%").page(params[:page]).per(200).order("published DESC")
        end
      else
        @resultsReceived_descr = false
        @sqlResults_descr = []
      end

      if params[:commit] == "Search Category Name"
          # Great, now lets figure out what sort of query we're after
          @searchQuery_cat = params[:a]
          @resultsReceived_cat = true
          if 
             @sqlResults_cat_published_size = Product.where("category_names like ? AND published = ?", "%" + params[:a] + "%", '1')  
             @sqlResults_cat_size = Product.where("category_names like ?", "%" + params[:a] + "%")
             @sqlResults_cat = Product.where("category_names like ?", "%" + params[:a] + "%").page(params[:page]).per(200).order("published DESC")
          end
        else
          @resultsReceived_cat = false
          @sqlResults_cat = []
        end

        if params[:commit] == "Search ID Str"
            # Great, now lets figure out what sort of query we're after
            @searchQuery_idstr = params[:i]
            @resultsReceived_idstr = true
            if 
               @sqlResults_idstr_published_size = Product.where("id_str like ? AND published = ?", "%" + params[:i] + "%", '1')  
               @sqlResults_idstr_size = Product.where("id_str like ?", "%" + params[:i] + "%")  
               @sqlResults_idstr = Product.where("id_str like ?", "%" + params[:i] + "%").page(params[:page]).per(200).order("published DESC")
            end
          else
            @resultsReceived_idstr = false
            @sqlResults_idstr = []
          end

    # Render the page when we're done.
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end

  end
end
```

Also is it possible to do a Product.where("title like ? OR categories like ? **AND published = ?**", "%" + params[:q] + "%", "%" + params[:q] + "%", **'1'**).page(params[:page]).per(200).order("published DESC")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Form**
4 forms are redundant. Implement the radio buttons directly sending with the form as param `:in` and the search term as `:q`.

```
<%= form_tag("/search", :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <% [ 'product title', 'product description', 'categories', 'ID string' ].each do |in| %>
    <br>
    <%= radio_button_tag 'in', in %>
    <%= in.humanize %>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

If you insist on putting different button texts each type of search, use a javascript hook on the radio buttons to change it.

**Controller**.
Abstract out the searches as named scopes in the model (see below). Since each type of search collects the same product model instances, its best practice to define the whole search scope on `Product`. Then your controller looks like:

```
def index
  @result_scope = Product.search(params[:in],params[:q])
  @results = @result.page(params[:page]).per(200).order("published DESC")
  @results_size = @result.count
  @results_published_size = @result.published.size
end
```

I omitted resultreceived etc variables since that can be worked out in the view knowing `params[:in]`. Use a helper method for this then call it in your index view template. You can also fork on this to know which result collection is put in @results. (If you need to know at all since you probably render the result products the same way no matter how I search for them.) So I just use one variable to pass results to the view.

This part is unecessary in the action if you use rails default rendering and your view template has the right path (this is called implicit rendering):

```
# Render the page when we're done.
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
end
```

**model**

```
class Pruduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  scope :search, lambda { |q,in|
    #...
  }
  scope :published, where(published: true)
end
```

Hope this helps.